# Error on Pyodbc 'pyodbc.connection' object has no attribute 'setencoding'

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

I want to send strings to my SQL server via pyodbc.
Some of my strings are conaining Character like "Ä,Ü,Ö,ã,ó".
While trying to send them i got an Error saying ="quotation mark after the character..."
I Read that i have to use "connection.setencoding(encoding='utf-8') and connection.setdecoding(encoding='utf-8')"
and here comes my Error.

After starting my script i get the following Error:

`"Attribute Error: 'pyodbc.Connection' object has no attribute ' setencoding'"`

here is my Connections String:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={FreeTDS},Server=-Serverip-;PORT=1433;DATABASE=-DataBase-;UID=-UID-;PWD=-PWD-;TDS_Version=7.2;charset=utf8')
cnxn.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')
```

Anyone an idea why im getting this kind of error?
or is there any other way?

Comment: Seems to be a known issue with old pyodbc versions. What version are you using?

Comment: re: "quotation mark after the character..." error — looks like the FreeTDS issue [here](https://github.com/FreeTDS/freetds/issues/317). TL;DR: If you are using a version of FreeTDS older than 1.1.23 then upgrading FreeTDS to the current stable version should make it work without having to resort to `.setencoding()`

Comment: I got the Answer: instead of charset=utf8 its ClientCharset=UTF-8.